# Bibtex error message while previewing document in Texmaker

Tags: bibtex, texmaker

I'm starting a document that has no bibliography for now in Texmaker. However, when I type F1 for a preview the following error message:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6400 64-bit) 
The top-level auxiliary file: RLS.aux 
I found no \citation commands---while reading file RLS.aux 
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file RLS.aux 
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file RLS.aux 
(There were 3 error messages)
```

Here's the example document that gives rise to these errors:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \title{Mínimos Cuadrados Recursivos (RLS)}
    \author{Juan Manuel Pérez Porrúa Pérez}

    \begin{document}
        \maketitle
    \end{document}
```

Do I need a bibliography for every document in Texmaker?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) are you by any change using some compilation route in texmaker that automatically runs bibtex for you? That might only be suitable for documents that actually need bibtex. You should probably just have it run pdflatex + preview instead.

Comment: The error messages are telling you that BibTeX couldn't find any citation commands, no (usable) `\bibliography` instruction, and no (usable) `\bibliographstyle` instruction. Given the simplicity of your sample code and the absence of any bibliography-related material, that's actually exactly as it should be. What you need to do -- as @daleif has already suggested -- is to figure out how to inform TeXmaker when, and when not, to invoke BibTeX during the compilation process. If there's no bibliography to create, it's pointless to try to involve BibTeX, isn't it?

Comment: If you can't figure out how to compile your documents without involving BibTeX and if your document doesn't contain a bibliography, you could als simply choose to ignore the BibTeX-related error messages: They create no harm as far as LaTeX is concerned.